# Até que ponto não é aconselhável usar uma ORM?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, engenharia-de-software, nhibernate, orm

Estou trabalhando em um sistema muito grande utilizando .NET (ASP.NET MVC) a aplicação requer um nível crítico de **desempenho**. Até que ponto vale ou não a pena utilizar uma ORM? Existe alguma ferramenta que eu possa comparar em termos de desempenho os ORM'S e SQL puro?

Eu sei que existe uma diferença de desempenho entre SQL puro e ORM, não sei se é os Active Record's ou os ORM's em gerais são mais lentos em comparação com SQL puro, caso considere usar um ORM, qual deles provavelmente tem o melhor desempenho: EF ou NHibernate?

Sei que tudo também depende da estrutura do banco e das boas práticas, mas de modo geral para um sistema muito grande considero uma ORM? Já que o custo beneficio em relação à manutenção do sistema é muito mais alto do que não utilizando.

Comment: Essa pergunta poderia ser considerada "Principalmente baseada em opiniões" ?

Comment: Prefiro não usar. ORM torna muito fácil "esquecer" que existe um banco de dados relacional na jogada, e o código começa a pender para formas ineficientes de manipular o banco.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Eu sou a favor de uma abordagem mista

- Utilize o ORM ao máximo para **melhorar a legibilidade e a produtividade**. No C# ou VB.Net é possível usar o LINQ, que é uma ferramenta extraordinária em termos de produtividade. Quanto mais simples melhor.
- Quando for necessário aumentar a performance, ou quando o ORM não oferecer as ferramentas adequadas para o trabalho, **estude mais a fundo o ORM escolhido** e busque informações na internet, e **só então, parta para o SQL**.

  Os ORM's geralmente permitem usar uma linguagem parecida com SQL, ou então permitem utilizar SQL com formatação específica, o que é um ponto intermediário.

### Qual escolher?

Trabalho com ambos, o NHibernate possui mais recursos, é mais flexível, e possui muitas ferramentas e bibliotecas de extensão, entretanto o EntityFramework é mais simples e mais fácil para se utilizar, além das ferramentas se integrarem ao Visual Studio.

- **Para um projeto que nasce com BAIXA demanda**

  Escolher entre EntityFramework e NHibernate, neste caso pode se reduzir a uma questão de costume, ou seja, **use aquele que é mais familiar**.

  **Se tiver que aprender uma delas, eu escolheria o EntityFramework**, ele usa tecnologias mais atuais, e está evoluindo rapidamente.

  E **se você já conhece ambos, iria de EntityFramework** também, pois é mais simples de se trabalhar, além de ter **integração com o Visual Studio**, o que ajuda muito na produtividade.
- **Para um projeto que nasce com ALTA demanda**

  Para um projeto que já vá nascer com grande carga de dados/usuários/expectativa (imagine um sistema para uma empresa gerenciar milhares de funcionários), ai eu ainda recomendaria o NHibernate... é uma tecnologia que com certeza não vai te deixar a desejar nada.

**Referências**

- [NHibernate X Entity Framework](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/aspnet/pt-BR/0f57b6d6-eb71-44b3-ad42-33ac8166cee3/nhibernate-x-entity-framework)
- [Entity Framework 5 and 6 vs NHibernate 3 – The State of Affairs](http://www.dennisdoomen.net/2013/03/entity-framework-56-vs-nhibernate-3.html) <sup>inglês</sup>
- [Entity Framework 6 vs NHibernate 4](http://www.devbridge.com/articles/entity-framework-6-vs-nhibernate-4/) <sup>inglês</sup>

Comment: Concordo com o ponto de vista do @miguel-angelo. O ORM facilita e muito sua vida, como você mesmo disse, o sistema precisa de um nível crítico de desempenho, nesse caso é muito bom você utilizar o ORM para consultas mais "SIMPLES" (entenda simples como consultas que não necessitem de um extremo e poderoso envolvimento das tabelas, como desnormalização, joins com muitas condições e coisas similares). Sem contar que muitas vezes, através do ORM, você consegue  ter uma legibilidade melhor do código e tbm poderá evitar muitos erros de escrita de query por conseguir ver + facil os relacionamentos.

Answer (score 25):

## Sobre o Entity Framework

A implementação do `DbSet<>` faz o contexto de dados carregar o registro do banco apenas uma vez durante o ciclo de vida do `Controller`. Portanto, a diferença de desempenho entre o sistema escrito com SQL puro para o sistema em Entity Framework chega a ser desprezível se o banco de dados estiver normalizado corretamente (ou seja, com chaves primárias únicas e evitando relacionamentos desnecessários, como tabelas que são atualizadas de vez em nunca, podendo ser substituídas por `Enums`). Por ser muito simples, é o ideal para o início de desenvolvimento de um sistema. A desvantagem é a falta de suporte a outros bancos, como o Oracle, por exemplo.

## Sobre o NHibernate

É uma solução mais antiga que o Entity Framework, advinda do Java quando o ORM começou. Possui mais opções de configuração e trabalha melhor com outros bancos de dados que não sejam SQL Server. Entretanto, a abordagem para *Code First* ainda é um tanto prolixa, o que o torna mais lento que o Entity Framework para iniciar um projeto em termos de produtividade, sendo mais recomendado para projetos grandes que já estejam implementados e trabalhem com grandes massas de dados, o que exige uma sintonia fina das configurações.

## Até que ponto não é aconselhável usar uma ORM?

Esta parte é um tanto baseada em opiniões, mas inicialmente eu diria que não há restrições, visto que os *frameworks* ORM possibilitam a execução de SQL puro em etapas em que haja gargalos de desempenho. Sendo assim, nem a produtividade nem o desempenho são comprometidos.

---

**UPDATE**

A Oracle [desenvolveu seu provedor de dados com o Entity Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/), finalmente. Com isto, está vencido o problema de conectividade entre Oracle e Entity Framework.

[Um tutorial também foi elaborado pela equipe do Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/oll/obe/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm) para sanar eventuais dúvidas que possam surgir na integração.

Answer (score 7):

Defensores do ORM dirão que isso não se aplica a todos os projetos: nem todos necessitam executar joins complexos; e que o ORM é uma solução 80/20, em que 80% dos usuários necessitam de apenas 20% das funcionalidades do SQL. Mas posso dizer que isso não tem sido verdade. Somente no início de um projeto se pode trabalhar sem a utilização de joins ou usando-os de maneira simplista. Depois, será preciso otimizar e consolidar consultas. Mesmo considerando que 80% dos usuários utilizem somente 20% das funcionalidades do SQL, 100% terão que violar a sua abstração para fazer o que precisa ser feito.

•   As vantagens da utilização de ORM desaparecem com o aumento da complexidade pois é necessário promover uma quebra da abstração forçando o desenvolvedor a lidar com SQL;

•   Objetos não são uma forma adequada de representação de queries relacionais;

•   Ao invés de se utilizar bases de dados relacionais e ORM como solução de todos os problemas, se seus dados são objetos por natureza utilize NoSQL;

•   Design OO não pode representar dados relacionais de forma eficiente, isto é uma limitação fundamental do design OO que ORM não pode lidar.

Resumindo: ORM e um tiro no pé no meu ponto de vista.

Answer (score 4):

A pergunta é bem opinativa, na época era bem aceita, tem opiniões aqui e decidi pôr a minha que é diferente.

## Porque usar

ORM é uma excelente ferramenta para dar alguma produtividade para criar CRUDs e acessos à dados quando se domina uma dessas ferramentas e precisa dessa produtividade. Ou seja, quando você faz códigos repetitivos que muda só o modelo de dados, mas no fundo o que está sendo feito é o de sempre e não muda muito, é uma mão na roda.

Também pode ser útil na mão de quem não sabe lidar bem com os mecanismos de persistência de dados. Não quer dizer que o ORM tornará tudo ótimo, mas há uma tendência da pessoa errar menos, principalmente em termos de segurança quando usa algo pronto.

Isso acaba implicando que sejam sempre códigos simples. Quando entra em sistemas complexos todo mundo sabe que tem que começar a contornar o ORM e fazer gambiarras para atender as demandas. E como o futuro sempre reserva incertezas, em algum momento você pode ter um monstro na mão e ele começa a ser pior do que se não tivesse usado.

Na verdade, nem acontece tanto assim, já que muitos sistemas não precisam de manutenção de tão simples que eles são.

## Porque não usar

Algumas pessoas adotam para não ter que lidar com SQL. Esse é um dos piores motivos para adotar ORM, inclusive porque qualquer coisa mais sofisticada obrigará usar SQL e do jeito mais difícil, e mesmo quando não precisa usar o SQL não quer dizer que não precisa saber modelar e fazer consultas de forma adequada. A parte difícil é criar os modelos e consultas, não é o SQL.

Outro motivo terrível para adotar o ORM é para facilitar a troca do banco de dados no futuro.

Isso não faz sentido porque quase ninguém troca o DB, e se trocar, o erro foi tão grande que o ORM não vai te salvar. Mesmo que troque, o ORM não faz tudo ficar lindo e maravilhoso. O ORM nivela por baixo, ele não funciona **bem** em banco de dados algum, salvo os usos mais básicos.

O mais comum da pessoa querer trocar o banco de dados é porque o ORM está criando um gargalo porque ele não aproveita bem os recursos do DB adotado. Ou seja, se você usar os recursos de forma direta e adequada para aquele DB sem passar pelo ORM não teria o problema.

Claro, isso sempre considerando que a pessoa saiba o que está fazendo. Quando a pessoa não sabe, ORM ou não, muda muito pouco, ela vai errar e a sorte vai definir se ela terá um pequeno ou um grande problema. Por acaso a maioria dos casos em que as pessoas usam ORM não faz muita diferença.

O problema da ideia que está fazendo algo simples é que no futuro pode deixar de ser simples, as coisas evoluem, e aí será um problema lidar com o ORM. Então tenha certeza de que o ORM nunca será um problema. Não basta não ser um problema hoje.

Vou concordar com a resposta que diz que as vantagens do ORM desaparecem quando se torna complexo; e que modelo de objetos não são bons para fazer consultas em banco de dados relacionais.

Outro motivo para não usar é porque há brigas religiosas sobre qual ORM usar, a tal ponto que há quem diga que deva implementar uma camada para poder trocar o ORM se for necessário. Nem quero comentar sobre essa atrocidade.

De fato, não é fácil achar qual é o ORM adequado para seu caso. E isso é importante porque você se casa com ele, o que dará para fazer com facilidade depende do que ele oferece, não é tudo igual.

Na prática as pessoas aceitam os defeitos do ORM escolhido nos casos em que ele não se encaixa bem. Ou seja, a solução é péssima.

As pessoas só escolhem o ORM certo depois de escolher muitas vezes o errado. E nem todos conseguem fazer essa evolução, a maioria só aceita o que tem, como dito antes.

## MicroORMs

Isso é outra coisa, inclusive as pessoas dizem que nem é ORM porque ele não implementa o padrão [Repository](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101692/101) ou pelo menos o [Active Record](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189082/101).

Pra mim ORM é só o mapeamento de dados entre o banco de dados e a linguagem já que nem sempre tem tipos compatíveis. Algumas pessoas consideram que tem que mapear na forma de objeto. Seja o que for, o chamado MicroORM é algo necessário e útil, a não ser que a linguagem seja integrada com o banco de dados, o que é muito raro.

O ORM *full* é um "facilitador" para fazer o modelo relacional do banco de dados com o modelo de objeto da aplicação.

Há algo chamado [impedance mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_impedance_mismatch). Que também é classificado como o [Vietnã da Computação](http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/the-vietnam-of-computer-science/).

[image: Ilustração da guerra do Vietnã com todo sofrimento]

## Outras soluções

Algumas pessoas resolveram o problema acabando com o relacional e adotando [NoSQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14533/101), assim poderia modelar como objeto no banco de dados. E aí eu não sei nem do que chamar isso, já que o nome apropriado já foi tomado pelo abuso do ORM. Não tem nada pior do que você modelar de forma ineficiente e que dificulta a programação e quase inviabiliza a consistência, só para não usar um ORM ou mudar sua aplicação para a forma que deveria.

É claro que existem casos que o NoSQL é útil, mas não para deixar de usar ORM. As pessoas que adotam o NoSQL admitem que o ORM é coisa ruim, mas resolvem tomar um veneno em vez de uma vacina.

Por que não adotar o modelo relacional na aplicação? Se tudo leva a isto, deveria ser óbvio que é a solução mais adequada. Ela é eficaz, não é difícil de usar, só não é tão bonitinha e não está na moda. Durante muito tempo as pessoas faziam assim e ninguém dizia que era um enorme problema. Um dia alguém apareceu com esse tal de ORM dizendo que era mais bonito fazer assim e as pessoas começaram adotar. Os problemas começaram aparecer depois, mas aí já tinha pegado moda.

## Entity Framework x nHibernate

O EF é oficial da Microsoft, evolui muito bem. Dizem que é mais fácil e está ficando rápido, até onde dá.

O NHibernate é mais complexo e poderoso, e tem mais problemas por ser mais antigo. Há quem diga que depois de um tempo você se arrepende de usar algo mais simples, o complexo acaba te ajudando na parte mais difícil. Hoje ele é bem pouco popular e é adotado ou por legado ou moda, ou porque quem tem um conhecimento mais avançado e adota ORM com uma pouco mais de consciência.

## Conclusão

Para coisas simples, para algo rápido, para situações em que não cause malefícios, o ORM pode ser usado, e muitos casos são assim.

Mas se quer um sistema mais bem feito, mais eficiente, que você tenha mais controle, que seja mais tranquilo para dar manutenção, onde quer algo de mais qualidade, o ORM não deveria ser usado.

Note que não estou dizendo que sempre que usar ORM não terá qualidade mínima, um prato de 5,00 pode ser nutritivo, gostoso e mata a fome. Um de 50,00 fará o mesmo de forma melhor. Tem hora para tudo.

Não existe caso único que deve ou não usar, depende da pessoa, depende do projeto e depende da demanda de qualidade.

Mesmo com algumas melhoras recentes, se quer eficiência e desempenho, não use ORM. Até para deixar próximo do ideal dá muito trabalho. Mas reforçando, sem conhecimento adequado, terá problemas para obter desempenho com ou sem ORM.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).