# NoSQL é tão problemático quanto parece?

Tags: banco-de-dados, nosql

Andei lendo sobre NoSQL nos últimos tempos, pois a primeira impressão que tive sobre a tecnologia foi boa. Fiz testes com MongoDB especificamente e achei muito prático e bem mais fácil do que bancos de dados relacionais. Também tive a impressão de que esse tipo de banco de dados é mais compatível com a orientação à objetos e por isso fiquei bastante interessado no assunto.

Acontece que lendo comecei a ver muitas opiniões negativas a respeito dessa tecnologia. Ouvi falar sobre o teorema CAP que implicaria que um banco de dados NoSQL ou não terá disponibilidade ou não terá consistência. Isso é uma coisa *muito* preocupamente, porque até hoje não encontrei casos em que é possível abrir mão de uma dessas coisas.

Na realidade, construir um sistema que pode vir a não ter os dados disponíveis ou não ter garantia de que os dados exibidos estão corretos me parece uma coisa extremamente problemática. Vi até um programador falando já que esse tipo de tecnologia provavelmente não vai ser muito usada, sendo que os bancos relacionais continuam sendo mais indicados.

Se por um lado tem tudo isso, por outro lado senti muito mais facilidade e naturalidade ao usar o NoSQL. Dessa forma, gostaria de saber: o NoSQL é tão problemático assim como parece? Não há nenhuma forma de contornar esses problemas? Ou o NoSQL realmente só tem alguns poucos usos nos quais os dados podem nem sempre ser corretos ou nem sempre disponíveis?

Comment: Lembre que o NoSQL não se aplica a qualquer caso e me parece que ele realmente abre mão de certos aspectos para favorecer outros justamente para contemplar aplicações como as Redes Socias, a SQL Magazine publicou um bom artigo recentemente sobre isto.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Primeiro eu te pergunto: você fez operações complexas como NoSQL? Você mediu adequadamente a performance em todas as situações?

## Ferramenta certa

[image: Carro com um cavalo dentro sendo transportado no banco de trás com a cabeça pra fora da janela]

Existe uma expressão popular que todo mundo conhece: ["Se a única ferramenta que você conhece é um martelo, todos os problemas parecem pregos"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument).

Não, esta expressão não cabe aqui, mas ela é adotada por muitos. Deveria ser conhecida outra que cabe nesta situação: "**Quando você tem um canivete suíço, vai querer brincar com todas as ferramentas**".

NoSQL é uma tecnologia interessante e tem sua serventia. Certamente é uma das ferramentas do canivete suíço que temos disponíveis. Mas ele não é uma faca, uma chave de fenda ou um saca-rolhas.

NoSQL é aquela ferramenta obscura que quase ninguém sabe para que serve (mesmo a maioria que usa). Mas mesmo assim as pessoas tentam usar, afinal se está lá, eu devo ser obrigado a usar, certo? Se tem outras pessoas usando deve ser bom.

## Confusão de conceitos

NoSQL é um nome que engloba várias tecnologias bem diferentes com uma característica em comum. Saber escolher a tecnologia mais adequada é importante também.

Só para citar as principais variantes:

- pares de chave e valor;
- colunares;
- baseado em documento;
- grafos.

Mesmo essas possuem subtipos. Tamanha são as variações que dificilmente vai encontrar duas tecnologias com as mesmas características.

Outros já deram algumas dicas que o assunto é mais complexo e você verá explicações erradas por todo lado.

## Durabilidade

Você fala em falta de disponibilidade. Eu vou imaginar que você está falando em falta de durabilidade, porque disponibilidade é uma das coisas que o NoSQL facilita.

Durabilidade é a propriedade da informação se manter permanente após sua execução. Em geral isso é obtido através da gravação em memória de massa (disco por exemplo).

Disponibilidade é a propriedade onde o banco de dados está respondendo às *queries* sempre que for requisitado. Não quer dizer que não haverá resposta, mas pode não acontecer agora.

De fato **algumas implementações não facilitam a durabilidade**, ou pelo menos não tem isso como prioridade. Mas é possível ter todos os dados duráveis de uma forma ou de outra.

## Consistência eventual

Tecnologias **NoSQL** costumam ser ótimas para obter **escalabilidade**.

Já a **consistência é problemática mesmo**. NoSQL basicamente aceita a tese da **consistência eventual**. Ou seja, em algum momento o banco de dados estará consistente. Inclusive em algum momento não definido estará durável, ou disponível.

Nem todos os problemas exigem que a consistência seja absoluta.

Então NoSQL troca uma capacidade por outra.

## Facilidade de uso

Esse não é o melhor motivo para escolher uma ferramenta, principalmente quando essa facilidade não é absoluta. Você precisa de anestesia geral para simplesmente quebrar o osso do nariz mas pode se manter consciente quando abre o cérebro. É contra intuitivo, mas é assim que funciona.

## Onde usar?

Se você é o Facebook, como vai tratar bilhões de transações por dia em um banco de dados?

Com NoSQL! **Se você é o Facebook você precisa de uma tecnologia assim**. E se você é o Facebook, não precisará de consistência absoluta na maior parte dos casos. E nos casos que precisa, vai criar uma aplicação que lidará com isso. Essa aplicação será complexa, mas é a única forma de fazer.

No Facebook também não precisa de características relacionais do banco de dados. Parte disso é pela característica própria da aplicação. Mas também ajudada pela forma como ela é desenvolvida. Quando eles pensam em adicionar algum recurso do software que se aproxime da característica relacional, ou se muda a forma de desenvolver o software, recusa-se a funcionalidade.

Já vi muitos "especialistas" em banco de dados reclamar da falta de um recurso no Facebook ou no Gmail. Segundo eles, seria um recurso trivial de implementar. Seria... em um banco de dados relacional.

Ninguém vai morrer ou ter prejuízo se demorar um pouco para receber um notificação de um amigo, se o número de *likes* não for 100% preciso no exato momento que está olhando. Os mais maldosos (ou realistas?) dirão que mesmo erros grotescos permanentes nesse site também não farão diferença alguma na vida de alguém :)

Então se você não é o Facebook (claro que é apenas um exemplo), não se preocupe tanto com NoSQL. Quem disser que NoSQL não é **nicho** provavelmente estará se comportando como *fanboy*. Dá até para discordar do tamanho do nicho, mas não é uma solução para tudo.

Por *default* você deve usar um banco de dados relacional. A maioria dos problemas reais onde banco de dados são usados se encaixa neste paradigma ou muito bem ou pelo menos de forma minimamente adequada. A maioria dos problemas possuem dados tabulares relacionados.

Uma cirurgia que cura uma doença rara no cérebro chama muita atenção, mas **a maioria das pessoas precisam apenas tirar o apêndice**. O que está na mídia não é o que todo mundo precisa é só o que chama atenção.

## Assunto do momento

Você ouve falar muito porque a mídia é assim, sempre tem o assunto da moda. Os profissionais mais qualificados costumam escrever muito na internet. Tecnologias de ponta (que quase sempre só são usadas em casos muitos específicos) ficam em evidência mais que as tecnologias maduras. Quando surgir outro assunto mais relevante, todo mundo falará dele e o NoSQL só vai ser falado quando for relevante. Tem até outros motivos para o assunto ter tanta repercussão, mas não cabe aqui.

Agora a moda é microsserviço que é uma extensão do NoSQL. Nessa metodologia NoSQL faz muito sentido, mas um relacional simples como o SQLite também faz (tem outros exemplos), em alguns casos. Microsserviço guarda semelhança com NoSQL nas dificuldades. Para conseguir **uma** característica complica todo o resto.

## Vida longa aos relacionais

Diversas tentativas de novos paradigmas de banco de dados tentaram desbancar a hegemonia do relacional e não conseguiram. Mas quase todos sobreviveram em nichos, alguns tiveram bastante destaque. O problema é quando você tenta usar para algo além do que ele foi feito.

O maior abuso é o modelo de documento. As pessoas acham que podem trocar tabelas por documentos. Esse modelo foi feito quando realmente tem documentos e não dados relacionados. A maioria dos problemas não são documentos, as pessoas tentam mudar o problema pra se encaixar nessa forma.

Bancos de dados relacionais são bem conceituados, atendem os requisitos do que é feito, talvez, em 99,9% das "aplicações do mundo real", e tem uma quantidade imensa de profissionais que dominam seu uso. Alguém deve pensar nele antes de qualquer outra alternativa. Primeiro pense na faca, ou quem sabe na chave de fenda. Se elas não resolvem o problema de forma adequada, aí você pensará em outra ferramenta.

**Não estou dizendo que você não deve estudar novos paradigmas de banco de dados. Se não estudar não saberá quando usá-los**. Assim como ocorre com linguagens, saber maneiras diferentes de resolver um problema não só ajuda saber quando usar uma ferramenta diferente, mas também saber como resolver o problema de um jeito diferente com a mesma ferramenta.

O problema é que a maioria aprende errado.

E de fato quase todos os bancos de dados relacionais relevantes estão criando formas diferentes de resolver certos problemas que são mais adequados a um NoSQL. Mais um motivo para não abandonar os relacionais. 10 anos depois alguns relacionais são capazes de lidar bem com todos os problemas, só não são muito pequenos. Outros são pequenos mas lidam só mais ou menos com esse tipo de problema.

Depois de ver muita gente trabalhando com isso vejo que usam do jeito errado. Fazem tudo simples demais e só funciona porque não precisava daquilo. Quando precisam fica tudo complicado demais ou então não funciona direito. Como em geral não era necessário esses problemas aparecem pouco.

Note que **uma tecnologia não exclui a outra**. O próprio Stack Exchange usa ambas. E ele tem as vantagens de cada. Mas no começo só usava SQL. E quando mudou, ninguém notou a diferença. Então é apenas um detalhe de implementação. A mudança foi relativamente simples.

Só não ache que o sistema financeiro de uma empresa vai ter o mesmo benefício. Pode até ter malefício. Já vi fazerem isso, mas o problema que dá não compensa.

Ainda temos uma **imensidão de problemas que exigem relações complexas**. Por que evitar um banco de dados relacional? Tenho visto desastres onde o relacional é o adequado mas a pessoa optou por NoSQL (ou NoRel que é o que essa tecnologia realmente é).

Na verdade o nome correto desse tipo de tecnologia devia ser NoConsistency porque é isso que realmente não tem. Cada vez mais elas estão usando relações e até SQL.

Em alguns casos para conseguir consistência abre-se mão da disponibilidade.

Como a maioria das vezes quer a consistência e a disponibilidade deve-se evitar o particionamento. Tudo isso faz parte do [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem). Você acha que não, mas funciona.

Este site é um dos 30 sites mais acessados do mundo e tem consistência, e disponibilidade, não tem particionamento. E atende bem sem sobressaltos. Você acha que precisa mais que isso?

O Stack Overflow (em inglês, o grandão) pode rodar em um servidor se quiser.

O tráfego do SO no Brasil é semelhante a um dos maiores e mais conhecidos sites brasileiros que tem um padrão de acesso muito parecido. Uma página descritiva que todo leem muito, e muito eventualmente alguém comenta algo ou mais eventualmente faz alguma operação de escrita, e esse site precisa de milhares de servidores, justamente porque adotou ferramentas erradas. E precisa de bem mais gente em TI para lidar com tudo, principalmente de desenvolvimento. Muitas dessas modas são vendidas como facilitadores, é insano.

## Conclusão

A melhor forma de aprender tudo isso é fazer um **estudo sério, aprofundado e consistente** sobre os assuntos. No processo pode até descobrir que não sabia muita coisa sobre banco de dados relacional (eu vi muito fã de NoSQL - pessoas que são referência - que não sabia usar relacional direito e tomou a decisão por causa disso). Caso não possa conduzir esses estudos adequadamente terá que confiar em pessoas aleatórias dizendo o que é bom para você. :P

Se você precisa de consistência absoluta, sim, ele é problemático, apesar de não ser inviável. O problema é que aí estará usando a ferramenta errada, terá muito trabalho para conseguir o que é "fácil" com outra ferramenta.

A grande pergunta que deve ser feita: por que "diabos" alguém escolhe usar NoSQL quando ele precisa de consistência absoluta? O mesmo vale pra disponibilidade que dá para conseguir um ou outro, ou ambos se abrir mão do particionamento, que é o motivo do NoSQL ter sido criado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 19):

[O Teorema CAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) (Consistency/Availability/Partition tolerance) se refere a integridade destes três items em um sistema distribuído, e não se refere particularmente a sistemas SQL ou NoSQL. O que importa no teorema é a questão do sistema distribuído e a impossibilidade de garantir estes 3 itens simultaneamente em tais sistemas.

Dito isto, sistemas distribuídos SQL tem suas características, assim como os NoSQL, cada um vai pender por priorizar uma das 3 características do teorema. Então a meu ver vale ponderar qual destas é prioridade (na aplicação) para a escolha do tipo de sistema, pois garantia dos 3 itens é o que o teorema diz que não haverá, seja SQL ou NoSQL.

- [Consistency models in nonrelational DBS](http://web.archive.org/web/20150510041549/http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-cloud-databases/w/wiki/320.consistency-models-in-nonrelational-dbs.aspx)
- [CAP Theorem, Eventual Consistency, NoSQL](http://venublog.com/2010/04/07/cap-theorem-eventual-consistency-nosql/)

Answer (score 13):

Primeiro de tudo basta entender uma coisa, em qualquer situação, em qualquer ocasião, em qualquer ponto da história da humanidade, sempre houve e haverá pessoas contra e a favor de mudanças.

Muitas tecnologias que diziam não ter futuro, por muitas vezes não tiveram futuro. Outras que diziam não ter futuro, acabaram se tornando o grande carro chefe de muitas empresas, tudo porque houve nesses momentos **PARADIGMAS** que foram desafiados. Nos casos de sucessos, foram vencidos e estabelecidos novos em seus lugares.

O **NoSQL** é uma tecnologia, um conceito, um novo paradigma ainda não tão bem visto, como muitos gostariam que fosse. Porém, isso não o torna menos eficaz que um velho paradigma como os **Bancos de Dados Relacionais**.

Muitos dos que comentam negativamente a respeito do **NoSQL** o fazem por estarem em uma zona de conforto dentro da tecnologia e *muitas vezes* não a estuda tããão a fundo para descobrir todo o  potencial por trás dela.

A questão de funcionalidade só pode ser respondida por um aprofundamento bem detalhado de sua necessidade, de uma pesquisa relacionada a alternativas para concepções e pelo velho fato da tentativa e acerto.

Ninguém vai acertar na primeira tentativa sempre, sempre terão erros no meio do caminho, mas que serão como bases para novos aprendizados e evitar cometer os erros passados.

Passado ao primeiro momento de explicar o medo ou a incerteza que muitos tem a tentar coisas novas, vamos responder as perguntas:

> o NoSQL é tão problemático assim como parece?

*"Os problemas da vida são do tamanho que a gente dá a eles." 
Mallu Magalhães*

Se você logo de cara criar esse bloqueio de que o NoSQL é TÃO problemático assim, para você, mesmo depois de algum tempo de estudo, ele será sim, tão problemático. Mas se tiver vontade de estudá-lo a fundo, podem ser probleminhas ou ciscos no seu caminho.
Sobre NoSQL na minha opnião, não é que ele seja complicado, é que ele faz parte de uma mentalidade que não tinhamos antes a respeito de tecnologias de gerenciamento e armazenamento de nossos dados.

> Não há nenhuma forma de contornar esses problemas?

Tem, sempre tem, estudo, estudo, estudo, estudo e quando sobrar um pouco de tempo, mais estudo. Lembro sempre de duas frases que me desafiam a encontrar a **forma** para esses problemas que parem `não ter forma de contornar`.

*"Prefiro o impossível, lá a concorrência é menor" - Steve Jobs*

e também.

_"Não sabendo que era impossível, ele foi lá e fez" - Jean Cocteau

Essas duas frases remetem a necessidade da primeira pergunta respondida e do fato das tentativas e erros para descobrir os caminhos alternativos.

> Ou o NoSQL realmente só tem alguns poucos usos nos quais os dados podem nem sempre ser corretos ou nem sempre disponíveis?

Pergunte ao Facebook ou outros casos de sucesso como StudyBlue também.
Eles usam porque suas soluções precisaram de algo a mais que em algum ponto dos seus projetos, viram que o esquema relacional não se tornara mais viável.
Assim sendo, volto a afirmar o ponto de que só pode decidir algo em relação a **NoSQL** e **Relacional** depois de um estudo aprofundado no projeto que deseja impor-lhes...

Se o tudo for apenas em intuito de aprender algo novo... Vale mais a pena ainda que aprenda sim e que use em seus projetos particulares, porque não existe cliente melhor pra testar novas tecnologias do que você mesmo... Tenho certeza que esse cliente vai lhe deixar testar isso. ;)

Abraços e desculpa o "ARTIGO" que escrevi kkk.

**edit: links para estudo**

[Introdução no SS](http://www.slideshare.net/PauloRobertoDonatilioRego/introduo-ao-nosql)

[Oracle NoSQL Overview and Practice](http://www.oracle.com/br/products/database/nosql/overview/index.html)

[No-SQL Database](http://nosql-database.org/)

[Mongo-DB](http://www.itexto.net/devkico/?p=682) *achei bem interessante, bem direto ao ponto*

[Mongo Documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/about/introduction/)

[NoSQL Data Modeling](http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)

[NoSQL relationship](http://robvolk.com/designing-for-relationships-on-a-no-sql-database/)

**[Livro indispensável: NoSQL Essencial](http://www.novateceditora.com.br/livros/nosql-essencial/)**

Answer (score 2):

Já existem cases de sistemas enormes e bem complexos construídos em cima de bases NOSQL. Creio que tais cases impedem qualquer um de dizer coisas como "NoSQL realmente só tem alguns poucos usos nos quais os dados podem nem sempre ser corretos ou nem sempre disponíveis". Certamente há formas de contornar. Só pra citar um exemplo, com Mongo DB, você pode "reinventar a roda" para tentar ter 2PC (Two Phase Commit - http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/perform-two-phase-commits/), enfim dá pra forçar a barra e ter soluções para outros tipos de limitações. A questão é: será que realmente vale a pena? Se você precisa tanto disso, não era melhor usar logo um RDBMS?

Answer (score -1):

A questão não é ser problemático, mas sim que a finalidade dele é outra e não substitui o relacional.

Sou dba, conheço os 2 principais rdbms do mercado e um nosql de um grande fornecedor o qual já trabalhei para ele.
Não defendo nenhum deles, nem fabricante, nem tecnologia.(nem vou fazer propaganda de graça)

Como rapaz já escreveu ali em cima, são para propósitos diferentes e noSQl nunca substituirá relacional. Apesar da modinha noSQL em que muitas empresas querem usar sem conhecer a fundo sua finalidade, ele pode ser bem usado para ganhar escalabilidade, tempo de resposta em grandes massas, desde que você possa abrir mão de algumas coisas importantes como consistência, etc.

Pois então, ele é problemático? Não! Para alguns fins é rápido e bom!
Quer garantias dos seus dados e que seu SGBD seja rápido, um bom dba do maior fabricante sabe que existem hardware, software apartados, options que podem transformar ele em um canhão, inclusive em grandes massas de dados no modelo relacional. Só que não é barato.

A decisão de construir um sistema passa por muitas questões, uma das mais importantes é a conta que vai dar alguns milhões de dólares... Tirando tudo isso cada produto tem seu lugar, no relacional este lugar é bem maior.
E eles continuarão como estão por um bom tempo...

Comment: Robie bem-vindo ao Stackoverflow em Português! Tente não ser tão agressivo nas suas respostas, afinal aqui ninguém é melhor que ninguém. Estamos aqui todos para ajudar a comunidade de programadores que falam português. Podemos todos ajudar sem insultar e sem agressividade. Continue participando.