# DB NoSql, quando usar?

Tags: facebook, nosql, oracle11c

Trabalho em uma empresa que o fluxo de dados não é tão grande, porém o quantidade de informações que já estão gravadas no banco são consideravelmente grandes....

Ontem na faculdade discutimos sobre o banco `NoSql`, sobre empresas grandes como Facebook e Yahoo que geram dados na casa do PetaByte a cada ano e que necessitam de uma considerável velocidade pra suas consultas e retornos aos usuários.....

Na minha empresa, utilizamos `Oracle 11c`, as vezes necessitamos consultar views enormes, e essas as vezes demoram um tempo considerável para nos retornar o que necessitamos...
Minha dúvida é se valeria a pena migrar as aplicações para bancos `NoSql`.... para assim conseguir uma melhor escalabilidade... Sera que seria uma migração muito árdua? E sera que valeria a pena arriscar?

Comment: Arriscar? Definitivamente não. Você pode obter alguma informação inicial aqui, mas a mudança é bem grande. Todos vão ter que aprender profundamente a nova forma. Se depois de saber **muito bem** como trabalhar com a nova tecnologia achar que vale o esforço, comecem fazer testes reais de migração e ver se conseguem realmente obter resultados melhores no seu caso específico. Tem boa chance de descobrir que não vale antes de tentar, ferramentas diferentes existem para solucionar problemas diferentes. Um martelo para furar a parede não é uma boa ideia. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14809/101

Comment: Será que o problema não é a sua view enorme? Existem estratégias para melhorar o desempenho de grandes volumes de dados relacionais. Uma delas pode ser particionar as tabelas do banco por exemplo. Recomendo vocês conversarem com um bom DBA antes de qualquer alteração radical.

Comment: unnn eu já havia lido esse post @bigow rs, mas devo confessar que me senti empolgado quando ouvi falar do NoSql....

Comment: @gmsantos, tem como voce citar um exp de estratégia?

Comment: Tabelas e Índices particionados no Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c12parti.htm

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa tomar cuidado se quiser pensar em adotar NoSQL. A principal pergunta que você deve responder é "que tipo de dados desejo armazenar?", e em seguida "qual o volume destes dados?".

NoSQL não é uma tecnologia que surgiu para substituir SQL tradicional, ela surgiu para resolver problemas de escalabilidade horizontal, [transações ACID](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) e armazenamento "poliglota", isto é, armazenamento de outras formas de dados além do clássico "linha X coluna" com junções/unions que estamos acostumados.