# Como gerar relatórios usando NoSQL?

Tags: nosql

eu possuo um documento Mensagem e no meu banco NoSQL eu posso ter milhares de mensagens da seguinte forma:

```
[{"origem":1,"destinatario":1,"created_at":"2016-12-20","conteudo":"P ligula pellentesque ultrices"},
{"origem":1,"destinatario":2,"created_at":"2016-12-21","content":"Vestibulum ante ipsum ."},
{"origem":1,"destinatario":3,"created_at":"2016-12-20","content":"Aliquam sit amet diam in ."},
{"origem":1,"destinatario":3,"created_at":"2016-11-20","content":"Aliquam sit amet diam in ."},
{"origem":1,"destinatario":4,"created_at":"2016-10-20","content":"Aliquam sit amet diam in ."}]
```

Estou com uma dúvida para gerar relatórios por exemplo: Quantidade de mensagens enviadas no mês 12, Quantidade de novos destinatários no mês 11.

Quantidade de mensagens no mês é fácil apenas percorro todas as mensagens e comparo se é de determinado mês e vou contando, mas para verificar a quantidade de novos destinatários no mês 12 eu tenho que percorrer todas as mensagens e verificar se o destinatário está em mensagens anteriores etc. É algo que demoraria bastante já que posso ter vários destinatários e  milhares de mensagens.

Não quero que façam para mim, mas creio que exista alguém mais fera em Nosql que possa dar uma dica de alguma ferramenta que gere isso de forma mais fácil ou de modelar meu banco de outra forma usando uma base de dados relacional.

Comment: A pergunta que eu faria é pra que usar NoSQL num caso onde claramente a informação é relacional. (se bem que o nome NoSQL já causa confusão, pq o fato de usar ou não SQL não devia ter nada a ver com ser relacional ou não - DBF, por exemplo é relacional, mas não usa SQL)

Comment: @Bacco o sistema usa Nosql por causa das centenas de conexões por minuto. Como banco de dados relacional é bloqueante então essa foi a melhor solução encontrada.

Comment: Realmente eu sugiro uma revisada nos conceitos todos. Não sei onde leu esse negócio de "bloqueante", mas talvez não seja exatamente o que você entendeu. NoSQL não traz vantagem nenhuma nesse sentido (a aplicação é sua, claro, faça como achar que deve. a sugestão é só no sentido de evitar a solidificação de conceitos errados).

Comment: Relacionado http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96409/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122452/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14533/101

Comment: Muito obrigado galera, vou dar uma estudada no assunto. o/

Comment: Emília, Eu uso um conjunto de ferramentas perfeita para esse tipo de reports, ELK da Elastic.co
https://www.elastic.co/webinars/introduction-elk-stack Você pode usar o Logstash para consumir seu BD e jogar para Elastisearch, o Kibana será usado para gerar seus reports. Qualquer dúvida só perguntar.

Answer (score 0):

Seu exemplo de mensagens é um JSON onde há um array que contém vários objetos. Presumo que a unidade de armazenagem em seu banco de dados é cada um objeto um desses objetos dentro do array, certo? Como é um documento, presumo, também, que esse NoSQL que está falando é um MongoDB, estou certo?
De forma geral, quando falamos de bancos desse tipo, a estrutura de dados sempre interfere na forma como lemos a informação, aliás, seu problema está relacionado a isso.
Para resolver esse problema, eu não utilizaria MongoDB, utilizaria CassandraDB, mas criaria mais de uma "tabela", uma seria essa que está mencionando e outra exclusiva para resolver seu problema, onde a chave seria o destinatário e precisaria somente de um valor, a data da criação da primeira mensagem. Tomando um trecho de uma [documentação](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/ddl/dataModelingAnalysis.html) do Cassandra:

> Application-side joins can be a performance killer. In general, you should analyze your queries that require joins and consider pre-computing and storing the join results in an additional table. In Cassandra, the goal is to use one table per query for performant behavior.