# Qual a melhor forma de se fazer comentários em post?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados

Como posso organizar um sistema de comentários em MySQL

Uma ideia seria:

```
id_post
id_comentario
id_user
comentario
```

Só que ocuparia muito espaço e não seria tão rápido assim processar 2000 comentários de `id_post` diferentes

Pensei também em utilizar *array*, exemplo:

```
id_post
comentário
```

Na coluna comentário ficaria:

```
user:5,comentário:teste;user:6:comentário:teste;
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Só você pode dizer qual é a melhor forma para seu caso.

A primeira forma pode ser muito interessante e muita gente acha que não. Faça algumas perguntas:

- Você precisa acessar o comentário de forma isolada ou ele sempre será acessado através do *post*? Se é uma associação direta agregada e não tem uma identidade própria a [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101) não costuma ser necessária. Quem trabalha com [NoSQL, que na verdade deveria se chamar NoRel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96409/101), faz muito isso e acham ótimo (em muitos casos é mesmo), o que muitos não percebem é que o modelo relacional dos RDBMSes é opcional.
- Normalmente vai ler todos os comentários juntos? Se a resposta anterior for sim e aqui também é sim, então tem grande chance de ser a melhor opção. Se vai ler tudo junto porque precisaria separar?

  2000 comentários em um post? Se tiver isto tem algo humanamente inadministrável, se tiver dezenas de comentários deve ter algo errado. Nem no Facebook costuma ter isso e quando tem é a mesma coisa que não tiver comentários, ninguém vai ler. Este site nasceu da observância que outros sites não conseguiam gerenciar essas coisas e acabam não servindo ao propósito.

  2000 comentários ao todo no sistema? Isso não faz "cosquinha".

Provavelmente eu faria a segunda opção, só criaria algum padrão para reduzir o custo de espaço:

Pode criar um caractere que indique a quebra do que é o usuário e o que é o comentário. Na verdade não pode usar o `;` a não ser que escape esse caractere no texto antes de gravar, e terá que tratar isso. A separação do usuário não importa tanto, pode ser a vírgula porque só tem números, certo? Nem precisa dizer que vem um comentário em seguida, depois da vírgula após o número do usuário sempre é um comentário que terminará onde tem esse caractere terminador. Se fizer do jeito que está pensando e alguém comentar ";user" melará seus dados, haverá um *text injection*.

```
65,teste;66,teste com \; escapado;
```

Pode usar um número, talvez na forma binária (4 bytes deve ser suficiente), no início indicando o tamanho dessa entrada toda, assim não precisa de um caractere terminador. Ele ocupará um pouco mais de espaço, mas é mais simples e mais seguro. Poderia fazer o número do usuário em forma binária também. Se usar a forma binária tem que tomar cuidado se usar em plataformas diferentes. Se usar como texto precisa ter tamanho fixo, que ocupará mais espaço, ou ter um separador, principalmente se o texto do comentário começar com número.

```
000♣000♣teste000¶000♠teste com ; escapado
```

Sem querer está usando ["NoSQL" do jeito certo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14533/101), produtivo e onde é útil.

Comment: Muito bem explicado, obrigado