# Armazenamento de variavéis do tipo List em um Banco de dados SQL-Server

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Boa Noite Pessoal,

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que faz um relacionamento entre um Jogador e um ou mais jogos(jogos online), o problema é que um jogo pode ter uma uma mais habilidades diferentes, gostaria de saber se tem uma maneira de deixar o registro de novas habilidades dinâmico, pois os mesmo podem ter muitas ou poucas(depende de cada jogo), com isso gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira de guardar uma lista ou um vetor em banco Sql-Server para que quando um jogo com mais ou menos habilidades fosse registrado não precisasse ficar gerando campos na minha tabela Jogo.
No caso eu geraria um único campo na tabela que seria essa lista e que poderia se chamar habilidades por exemplo e nela ia guardando as habilidades de cada jogo que o usuário registrasse

Comment: Sugestão, você teria que ter uma tabela com o COD_H e HABILIDADE, e outra tabela com os campos COD_D, COD_H, COD_Jogador, Qtd. Depois, na hora de solicitar mostre o todos os dados relacionados a um único jogador.

Comment: De uma lida nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/278780/qual-a-melhor-forma-de-se-fazer-coment%c3%a1rios-em-post/278783#278783) Não sei se seria o melhor para o caso, mas é algo muito interessante.

Comment: @RORSCHACH pela sua lógica então eu teria uma tabela só com os códigos de habilidades, mas o problema é que seria meio invalido eu criar uma tabela só para as habilidades pois talvez eu nunca mais use a mesma, pois cada jogo tem sua habilidade específica, por exemplo no Counter Strike eu registraria a patente do jogador e só, porem se o jogador jogasse League of Legends eu teria que registrar o Elo dele que é equivalente a patente, o nível e a posição que ele joga por exemplo,

Comment: @Barbetta Eu não pensei na possibilidade de trabalharmos com um banco não relacional pois eu e os integrantes do meu grupo não temos conhecimento do mesmo

Comment: @GiovanniPreivatti Você leu a pergunta? lá é uma alternativa com banco relacional, eu não acho que seja o ideal para o seu caso, porém vale a leitura. Quanto a sua pergunto, acredito que seria melhor você adicionar a modelagem feita, assim a comunidade pode te ajudar melhor quanto a isso.

Comment: @Barbetta obrigado, irei fazer isso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Solução 1:

Você pode ter 4 tabelas:

`Jogadores`  : Armazena o jogador.

`Jogos`      : Armazena os jogos.

`Habilidades`: Armazena todas as habilidades de um jogo.

`Relacao`    : Relaciona quais habilidades um jogador tem, essas por sua vez faz relação com o jogo.

*Exemplo:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Vantagens:**

1. Query simples para ter os resultados.

**Desvantagens:**

1. Não é possível relacionar um jogador a um jogo, sem informar uma habilidade pelo menos.
2. Não é possível reaproveitar o cadastro de habilidade para outros jogos.

> Solução 2:

5 tabelas...

`Jogadores`  : Armazena o jogador.

`Jogos`      : Armazena os jogos.

`Habilidades`: Armazena as habilidades.

`Relacao`    : Relaciona quais habilidades e de qual jogo um jogador tem.

`Jogos_Habilidades`  : Relaciona quais habilidades tem um jogo. Essa tabela só serve pra carregar quais habilidades estão cadastradas para um jogo.

*Exemplo:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Vantagens:**

1. Você pode utilizar o mesmo cadastro de habilidade em `n` jogos.
2. É possível relacionar um jogador a um jogo, sem informar nenhuma habilidade.

**Desvantagens:**

1. Query um pouco mais complicada.

> Espero que ao menos te dê uma ideia de como pode fazer. Eu, iria pela solução 2.

Script do modelo da solução 2:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [public];

CREATE TABLE [public].habilidades ( 
    id                   int NOT NULL   IDENTITY,
    nome                 varchar(200)    ,
    CONSTRAINT Pk_habilidades PRIMARY KEY ( id )
 );

CREATE TABLE [public].jogadores ( 
    id                   int NOT NULL   IDENTITY,
    nome                 varchar(200)    ,
    CONSTRAINT Pk_jogador PRIMARY KEY ( id )
 );

CREATE TABLE [public].jogos ( 
    id                   int NOT NULL   IDENTITY,
    nome                 varchar(200)    ,
    CONSTRAINT Pk_jogos PRIMARY KEY ( id )
 );

CREATE TABLE [public].jogos_habilidades ( 
    jogo                 int NOT NULL   ,
    habilidade           int NOT NULL   ,
    CONSTRAINT pk_jogos_habilidades PRIMARY KEY ( jogo, habilidade )
 );

CREATE INDEX idx_jogos_habilidades ON [public].jogos_habilidades ( habilidade );

CREATE INDEX idx_jogos_habilidades ON [public].jogos_habilidades ( jogo );

CREATE TABLE [public].relacao ( 
    jogador              int NOT NULL   ,
    jogo                 int NOT NULL   ,
    habilidade           int NOT NULL   ,
    valor                varchar(100)    ,
    CONSTRAINT Pk_relacao PRIMARY KEY ( jogador, habilidade, jogo )
 );

CREATE INDEX idx_relacao ON [public].relacao ( jogador );

CREATE INDEX idx_relacao_0 ON [public].relacao ( habilidade );

CREATE INDEX idx_relacao_1 ON [public].relacao ( jogo );

ALTER TABLE [public].jogos_habilidades ADD CONSTRAINT fk_jogos_habilidades FOREIGN KEY ( habilidade ) REFERENCES [public].habilidades( id ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE [public].jogos_habilidades ADD CONSTRAINT fk_jogos_habilidades_jogos FOREIGN KEY ( jogo ) REFERENCES [public].jogos( id ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE [public].relacao ADD CONSTRAINT fk_relacao_jogadores FOREIGN KEY ( jogador ) REFERENCES [public].jogadores( id ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE [public].relacao ADD CONSTRAINT fk_relacao_habilidades FOREIGN KEY ( habilidade ) REFERENCES [public].habilidades( id ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE [public].relacao ADD CONSTRAINT fk_relacao_jogos FOREIGN KEY ( jogo ) REFERENCES [public].jogos( id ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado, me ajudou muito