# O que é EdgeDB?

Tags: banco-de-dados

É bastante comum vermos discussões do tipo [Como escolher entre NoSQL e SQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122452/5878) ou mesmo perguntas que questionam qual banco é melhor. Ao ler mais a fundo vemos que cada tipo de banco busca resolver um tipo de problema específico, o que geralmente tem como consequência ele se adaptar muito bem com uma solução e muito mal em outras.

Esta semana acabei me deparando em um vídeo com o [EdgeDB](https://www.edgedb.com/):

> **The next generation database**
>
> *EdgeDB combines the simplicity of a NoSQL database with relational model’s powerful querying, strictness, consistency, and performance.*

Pela descrição parece buscar mesclar os dois mundos relacional e NoSQL.

Com o objetivo de entender melhor essa ferramenta:

- O que é o EdgeDB?
- O que realmente significa essa combinação de relacional com NoSQL?

Comment: Você não sabe? Eu também não, mas fiquei interessado se fizeram algo bom ou é marketagem, se eu descobrir eu venho contar pra você: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWrPg.jpg

Comment: _" Como escolher entre NoSQL e SQL? "_ pelo pouco que li, vamos ter que atualizar essa pergunta se esse EdgeDB realmente for "pra frente": 
_" Como escolher entre NoSQL, SQL e MistãoSQL? "_ ou _"Como escolher entre NoSQL, SQL e MixedSQL"_.

Comment: Não sei se vou responder, mas pelo que entendi é o PostgreSQL, que é ótimo pra quase tudo que precise fazer no modelo relacional, e resolve bem ou muito bem a maioria dos cenários onde a pessoa pensaria no NoSQL, e se considerar apenas o modelo de documento quase todos cenários, e eles colocaram uma camada em cima para facilitar o acesso de jeito que eles acham que deveria ser e que talvez atraia os pessoa que gosta de NoSQL mas não consegue aprender lógica relacional tradicional. Ou seja, nada novo, que faça o que não dava para fazer antes. Reforça que NoSQL puro raramente é útil.

Comment: O termo "NoSQL" já é um problema. Em xBase sempre se acessou DB Relacional sem precisar de SQL, quer mais "no sql" do que isso?.  O fato de ser grafo ou relacional independe totalmente da linguagem ou interface para se obter os dados. Provavelmente a pergunta linkada seria "usar relacional e não-relacional" ou "relacional ou grafo", coisa que o valha. O fato do termo inadequado ter sido consagrado para o não relacional reflete muito do público que usa sem saber bem a razão..

Comment: No momento estou assistindo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xn9kumWbjGU para ver se fala algo interessante.

Comment: @Bacco que é oque eu falo em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96409/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14533/101. Vendo o vídeo o cara afirma que a gente não pensa com tabelas. Ele pode fazer isso, e monte de gente pode ter entrado nessa onda, mas eu penso com tabelas, assim como prefiro composição do que herança. Provavelmente é um produto para nutelados.