# Como funciona o padrão Repository?

Tags: banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, repository

Estava dando uma estudada num *framework* em PHP chamado `Symfony`.

Quando estava estudando sobre a pesquisa ao banco de dados, percebi que há algumas diferenças em relação às buscas, como em *frameworks* como CakePHP 2 e Laravel 4.

Ao invés de utilizar um *model* que por si só já faz a consulta, ele apenas define como obter e definir os dados da entidade.

Exemplo:

```
class Usuario
{

     /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nivel_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $nivelId;

    public function setNivelId($value)
    {}
}
```

Não há nenhuma herança para outra classe, mas apenas a classe em si para representar os dados da tabela.

Aí, na hora de obter os dados, ao invés de fazer chamadas como `Usuario::findByNivel` diretamente do modelo, vejo uma codificação totalmente diferente.

```
$usuarioRepo = $this->getDoctrine()
                     ->getRepository('AppBundle:Usuario');

// Depois de obter o repository, posso fazer as consultas no banco

$usuario = $usuarioRepo->find($id);
```

Percebi então que esse `getRepository` tem algo relacionado ao padrão `repository`.

- Como funciona esse padrão?
- Qual problema ele resolve?
- Existe diferença entre esse *pattern* e os *models* utilizados em outros *frameworks*?

**Observação**: Não vou colocar a *tag* PHP porque foi somente um exemplo utilizado através da linguagem. Qualquer resposta sobre *repository* é bem-vinda ;)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## Definição

A grosso modo podemos dizer que ele é uma forma de abstrair a persistência de dados. Ele deixa o mecanismo de como os dados são acessados isolados das regras de negócio. Não é a entidade e não é a conexão que faz a persistência, é o repositório, que é uma classe independente com as responsabilidades [desacopladas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101). Então acessa os dados como uma coleção de dados quaisquer, como se estivesse na memória, não interessa muito como eles estão armazenados.

## Vantagens

Isso permite não só trocar facilmente o banco de dados, mas toda a lógica de leitura e escrita de dados (*log*, cache, coordenação de transação e distribuição, autorização, etc.). O que também é ótimo para facilitar a criação de testes formais, se bem feito.

## Composição

Por isso é muito comum, mas não obrigatório, que ele seja implementado através de uma interface ou classe abstrata que estabelece o contrato básico do que pode ser feito para persistir os dados.

É comum que ele possua as ações básicas de todo CRUD: `add`, `delete`, `edit`, `get` (para o `Id`), e `list` ou `find` (para filtrar dados da coleção). Pode haver variações disto e pode usar outros padrões de projeto para flexibilizar seu uso.

Exemplo de interface que cria  este contrato (em C#):

```cs
public interface IRepository<T> where T: IEntity {
    IEnumerable<T> List { get; }
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    T FindById(int Id);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DataBase/Repository.cs).

Cada entidade do repositório terá que implementar esses métodos de acordo com as necessidades.

Quanto mais inteligente for o repositório mais ele pode ajudar. Quanto mais ele possui conhecimento do dispositivo de persistência e estrutura dos dados, mais ele consegue fornecer abstrações e automatizações do processo, livrando o programador de fazer muita coisa manual.

## Problemas que ele resolve

Quando você deixa para as regras de negócio cuidarem da consultas ao banco de dados (ou outro meio de persistência) você espalha-as por todo o código, e alterações na estrutura dos dados, na forma de persistência, ou outras alterações que afetem as consultas de alguma forma, obrigam atualizar todo o código.

Note bem que é comum as regras de negócio precisarem especificar a consulta em si, necessária para seu uso. Nada errado com isso, o que não pode, segundo este conceito, é que a **forma** da consulta seja definida na regra de negócio. Não pode definir como o mecanismo fará a consulta. Falando mais claramente (mesmo sendo uma simplificação), não pode colocar o código SQL na regra de negócio.

## Onde encontramos ele

Você pode criar seu próprio mecanismo de repositório ou pode usar um pronto. Muitos destes *frameworks* MVC, tão famosos hoje, possuem um mecanismo próprio de repositório, ou algo parecido. Acredito que o Ruby on Rails criou o padrão de ter estas coisas juntas e devido ao seu sucesso o que veio depois sempre copiou o ideia de solução [*turnkey*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnkey). É muito comum este padrão funcionar junto com o [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping) (parece que o Hibernate começou isso). Talvez por isso há alguma confusão dele com o *model*.

Seu uso é aplicado com o padrão de [injeção de dependência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21319/101), conforme mostrado no exemplo da pergunta.

## Como deve ser, e como é usado

Que fique claro que ele não está relacionado com a regra de negócio. Nem com os dados, nem com seus comportamentos.

Alguns gostam de implementar repositórios em cima de um repositório pronto`</sarcasmo>`.

Alguns gostam de usá-lo quando não precisa. É uma camada a mais de abstração, que é um dos problemas mais recorrentes no desenvolvimento de software "moderno".

> Todos os problemas da computação podem ser resolvidos com um nível adicional de abstração, exceto o problema de ter níveis de abstração demais

> -- há contradições quem é o autor

A minha experiência mostra que ele não resolve tudo. Achar que pode criar uma aplicação universal eficiente e adequada para qualquer tipo de persistência e cenário é, no mínimo, tolo.

Claro que a solução é boa, só não é perfeita.

O que eu sei é que há muita opinião sobre qual é o jeito certo de usar este padrão. O que mostra que ele tem problemas. Não estou o criticando, apenas deixando claro que não há unanimidade sobre ele. E isso deve ser levado em conta antes de adotá-lo. Adote com cuidado, tendo certeza que ele é a solução e não um novo problema.

Há controvérsia no que deve entrar no repositório específico de cada entidade. Alguns dizem que deve ser puro e só as operações básicas genéricas típicas de CRUD, como as citadas acima, devem estar no repositório. Outros acham que especializações e quaisquer facilidades extras de como acessar os dados podem ser acrescentadas. Questiona-se até onde isso já não está entrando na seara da regra de negócio.

## Abstração das consultas

É comum precisar ter uma linguagem genérica para representar as consultas nas regras de negócio garantindo a abstração dos mecanismos. Isso é especialmente necessário quando pode ter mecanismos que não seguem o modelo de banco de dados relacional SQL.

Exemplos: [LINQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html).

Em geral elas acabam sendo limitadas por ter que adotar o padrão do mínimo denominador comum.

Nem sempre a tradução casa bem e esconder os detalhes concretos pode passar a ideia errada dos custos de sua utilização.

## Quando adotar

Precisa tudo isto sempre? Não, muitas vezes é exagero.

É muito fácil perder tempo demais e ter benefício de menos.

Uma coisa que sempre me pergunto antes de adotar alguma coisa é se vai me poupar trabalho ou aumentar o que eu tenho que fazer. Nem sempre dá para responder facilmente, principalmente sem ter experiência com aquilo que está avaliando.

Por isso que eu digo que precisa conhecer todas ferramentas para saber o que fazer.

> [Quando você só tem um martelo, todos os problemas parecem pregos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument)

> -- há contradições quem é o autor

Só que eles não são. O que tem de gente martelando parafuso por aí... E pior, eles têm certeza que estão fazendo o certo.

As pessoas precisam aprender automatizar mais o desenvolvimento de software para não ter [espeto de pau](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casa_de_ferreiro,_espeto_de_pau).

## OOP

Há o mito sobre programação orientada a objeto que ela foi a salvação do desenvolvimento de software. Está longe de ser verdade. Ela até trouxe alguns problemas justamente porque as pessoas passaram achar que é a solução definitiva para tudo.

Não existem provas, ou mesmo evidências empíricas, que OOP é melhor que outro paradigma. Claro que ele ajuda muito em alguns cenários, como em casos de GUI, alguns tipos de jogos, etc.

Já começa que muitas vezes as pessoas falam muito sobre OOP sem entender realmente o que é, seus objetivos, como usar corretamente. E é fácil entender porque isso ocorre.

Não há uma definição canônica do que é OOP. Eu mesmo não entendo totalmente o que é, por isso não defendo com unhas e dentes, como alguns fazem. Não posso defender o que não tenho certeza do que seja. E é comum as pessoas falarem que usam OOP quando nem é verdade. Classe não é sinônimo de OOP, até porque elas nem são necessárias neste paradigma.

Eu tentei achar um artigo do Joel Spolsky onde ele fala das "únicas três balas de prata da programação". Se me lembro bem são:

- **Linguagens de alto nível** - acho que todos concordam que sair no *Assembly* trouxe uma mudança fundamental em como programamos os computadores e um salto na produtividade .
- **Gerenciamento automático de memória** - algo tão importante que hoje praticamente não há linguagem *mainstream* que não faça isto nela própria ou em biblioteca padrão, ainda que parcialmente. C é, talvez, a única exceção.
- **Modularização** - houve um tempo que as aplicações eram bem pequenas e era fácil dar manutenção nelas. Com o aumento dos recursos computacionais, aplicações mais complexas começaram ser desenvolvidas. Mesmo nos primórdios. Mas o humano não conseguia administrar essas bases de código complexas. Modularizar foi a solução que permitiu uma explosão de aplicações complexas.

Esqueça OOP, Agile, TDD, *patterns* ou outras supostas balas de prata. Tudo isso ajuda mas não resolve tudo. Nada disso fez mudanças fundamentais no processo de desenvolvimento de software. A fixação por certas tecnologias ou metodologias talvez ocorra por causa do [efeito Dunning-Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

#### Modularização

A [modularização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223549/101) pode ser feita em qualquer paradigma. Então é possível fazer procedural de forma organizada muito bem, adotando esta prática. Claro que algumas linguagens não facilitam isso, mas é culpa dela e não do paradigma. Na verdade o procedural incentiva mais a modularização que a OO. O fato de algumas pessoas não entenderem, ou seguirem isso, é outro problema.

A modularização é a base de OOP, mas muitos entendem o contrário. Há uma definição (entre as diversas) que diz que orientação a objetos é aproximar os comportamentos dos estados que eles manipularão. Claro que isso faz algum sentido, mas não do jeito que as pessoas fazem.

## Por que estou falando de OOP nesta pergunta?

Porque os padrões de projeto famosos, como os do [Gang of Four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) vieram, em grande parte, para dar melhor entendimento do uso de OOP. Vieram para mostrar como modularizar as classes que estavam virando [*god objects*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

O [Repository Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) é mais um padrão que resolve o problema das pessoas usarem OOP sem saber o que fazer. Ele promove a [separação de conceitos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), que é um princípio fundamental que OOP mal usado tem ido contra.

Ele promove o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), que acho ser o princípio mais importante da programação, e que a maioria dos programadores não conseguem aplicar corretamente - na verdade nunca vi tanta violação deste princípio como ocorre hoje, e as pessoas nem conseguem perceber que isso ocorre.

Ele só tenta mostrar o óbvio, abstrações/generalizações são necessárias em sistemas complexos, mas não mostra o que deveria ser óbvio, que sistemas simples não precisam disto.

Lembre-se que apesar da herança ser um mecanismo fundamental da OO, ela deve ser evitada tanto quanto possível porque é um [acoplamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101). Os padrões promovem o desacoplamento. O que pode ser feito em qualquer paradigma. Em alguns é até natural, em OOP não. Bem-vindo à era da componentização, da composição.

## Conclusão

Estes maus usos de tudo o que eu disse aqui ocorrem porque as pessoas preferem a informação rasa. A falta dos detalhes causa o mal pior, o uso errado da coisa certa. Quantas pessoas clicam nos *links* encontrados e vão fundo na informação até ter tudo o que precisam?

Pesquisando sobre o assunto vejo mais pessoas cometendo erros com este padrão do que acertando. Mas sei lá, se está resolvendo, quem sou eu pra reclamar. Só é [complicado quando não resolve e a pessoa não percebe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: Você mereceu, cara. Parabéns pela grande (literalmente e alegoricamente) resposta.

Comment: Parabéns @bigown estava procurando exatamente isso.