# Para que serve a classe Context?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework, contexto

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em ASP.NET MVC com mapeamento usando o Entity Framework, ao observar alguns padrões vejo muito o uso da classe `Context`, pra que ela serve e o que deve conter na mesma?

Comment: Fala da `DbContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Entity Framework implementa um padrão de projeto chamado [Repository](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101692/101). Ele tem um mecanismo complexo que controla o acesso aos dados e dá uma aparência de simplicidade para seu código. Ele não tem todas informações do que precisa fazer, parte é seu código que sabe. Como juntar esse mecanismo complexo com seu código e tudo parecer uma coisa só? Herança. A classe `DbContext` é esse mecanismo, então você herda dela e coloca o que falta, por exemplo quais são suas tabelas, relacionamentos e outras configurações do seu modelo.

[Mais sobre a classe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext?view=entity-framework-6.2.0).

Um exemplo de implementação dela:

```
namespace EFTutorials
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class SchoolDBEntities : DbContext
    {
        public SchoolDBEntities()
            : base("name=SchoolDBEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StudentAddress> StudentAddresses { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<View_StudentCourse> View_StudentCourse { get; set; }

        public virtual ObjectResult<GetCoursesByStudentId_Result> GetCoursesByStudentId(Nullable<int> studentId)
        {
            var studentIdParameter = studentId.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("StudentId", studentId) :
                new ObjectParameter("StudentId", typeof(int));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<GetCoursesByStudentId_Result>("GetCoursesByStudentId", studentIdParameter);
        }

        public virtual int sp_DeleteStudent(Nullable<int> studentId)
        {
            var studentIdParameter = studentId.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("StudentId", studentId) :
                new ObjectParameter("StudentId", typeof(int));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("sp_DeleteStudent", studentIdParameter);
        }

        public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<decimal>> sp_InsertStudentInfo(Nullable<int> standardId, string studentName)
        {
            var standardIdParameter = standardId.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("StandardId", standardId) :
                new ("StandardId", typeof(int));

            var studentNameParameter = studentName != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("StudentName", studentName) :
                new ObjectParameter("StudentName", typeof(string));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<decimal>>("sp_InsertStudentInfo", standardIdParameter, studentNameParameter);
        }

        public virtual int sp_UpdateStudent(Nullable<int> studentId, Nullable<int> standardId, string studentName)
        {
            var studentIdParameter = studentId.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("StudentId", studentId) :
                new ObjectParameter("StudentId", typeof(int));

            var standardIdParameter = standardId.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("StandardId", standardId) :
                new ObjectParameter("StandardId", typeof(int));

            var studentNameParameter = studentName != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("StudentName", studentName) :
                new ObjectParameter("StudentName", typeof(string));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("sp_UpdateStudent", studentIdParameter, standardIdParameter, studentNameParameter);
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/EntityFramework/Context.cs).

[Fonte](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/dbcontext.aspx).