# Quais são as funções de um ORM?

Tags: orm

Quais ações um ORM deve suprir?

O que ele deve ou não fornecer ao desenvolvedor, ou qual seu papel dentro de um sistema?

Comment: Quando você fala implementar um ORM, você diz desenvolver um ou utilizar um?

Comment: Com isso, eu acho que ela está muito ampla. A resposta teria que ensinar a desenvolver um ORM todo, e isso pode englobar muita coisa. Aconselho você abrir uma pergunta e postar o que você já tem, e fazer a pergunta em cima da dúvida real, em seu caso o hasMany.

Comment: Se a duvida for diferente do que foi perguntado, sugeriria elaborar uma pergunta separada, ou então complementar esta com mais detalhes, mas sem mudar o foco. Já tem duas respostas extensas que correm o risco de ser invalidadas por causa disso. Como você já tem um bom tempo de site, já sabe como funciona.

Comment: Não tem como responder isso. Cada ORM tem as suas particularidades. Alguns se encaixam em Micro ORM, como é o caso do [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net). Ele por exemplo faz várias coisas, mas não o hasMany. Porém, muitos o consideram como ORM, e ele é criado pela SE e utilizado em todos os sites da rede.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Introdução

[Object-Relational Mapping (ORM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) é uma técnica que permite consultar e manipular dados de um banco de dados usando um paradigma orientado a objetos. Ao falar sobre ORM, a maioria das pessoas está se referindo a uma biblioteca que implementa a técnica de mapeamento objeto-relacional, daí a frase "um ORM".

Uma biblioteca ORM é uma biblioteca completamente normal escrito no idioma de sua escolha que encapsula o código necessário para manipular os dados, para que você não use o SQL mais; você interage diretamente com um objeto na mesma língua que você está usando.

Por exemplo, aqui é um caso completamente imaginário com uma linguagem pseudo:

Você tem uma classe livro, que pretende obter todos os livros de que o autor é "Linus".

Manualmente, você faria algo assim:

```
book_list = new List();
sql = "SELECT book FROM library WHERE author = 'Linus'";
data = query(sql); // I over simplify ...
while (row = data.next()){
     book = new Book();
     book.setAuthor(row.get('author');
     book_list.add(book);
}
```

Com uma biblioteca ORM, ele ficaria assim:

```
book_list = BookTable.query(author="Linus");
```

A parte mecânica é realizado automaticamente através da biblioteca ORM.

## Prós e contras

**Usando ORM poupa muito tempo porque:**

- DRY: Você escreve seu modelo de dados em um só lugar, e é mais fácil
  de atualizar, manter e reutilizar o código.
- Um monte de coisas é feito automaticamente, de manipulação de banco
  de dados para I18N.
- Obriga-nos a escrever o código MVC, que, no final, torna seu código
  um pouco mais limpo.
- Você não tem que escrever SQL mal-formado (a maioria dos
  programadores Web realmente manda mal nisso, porque o SQL é tratada
  como uma "sub"-linguagem, quando, na realidade, é uma linguagem muito
  poderosa e complexa).
- Sanitização; usar *prepared statements* ou transações é tão fácil quanto chamar um método.

**Usando uma biblioteca ORM é mais flexível porque:**

- Ele se encaixa em sua forma natural de codificação (é a sua língua!).
- Ele abstrai o sistema DB, para que possa alterá-lo sempre que quiser.
- O modelo é fracamente ligada ao resto da aplicação, assim você pode
  alterá-lo ou usá-lo em qualquer outro lugar.
- Ele permite que você use OOP como herança de dados sem dor de
  cabeça.

**Mas ORM pode ser uma dor:**

- Você tem que aprender, e as bibliotecas ORM são ferramentas não
  leves;
- Você tem que configurá-lo. Mesmo problema.
- O desempenho é OK para consultas habituais, mas um mestre SQL sempre
  fazer melhor com seu próprio SQL para grandes projetos.
- Ele abstrai o DB. Enquanto é OK se você sabe o que está acontecendo
  por trás da cena, é uma armadilha para novos programadores que podem
  gravar declarações muito gananciosos, como uma batida pesada em um
  loop for.

"Traduzido de: [What is an ORM and where can I learn more about it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279613/what-is-an-orm-and-where-can-i-learn-more-about-it)

Answer (score 13):

A própria descrição da tag já dá informações suficientes sobre o que é um ORM.

### O que é?

A sigla significa *Object-Relational Mapping*, mapeamento objeto relacional em tradução livre.

É uma técnica utilizada para fazer o mapeamento entre sistemas orientados a objetos e bancos de dados relacionais, onde as tabelas do banco de dados são representadas em classes e os registros das tabelas seriam instâncias destas classes.

Exemplo:

**Tabela:**

```
Pessoa
-----------------------------
Id               Integer(10) 
Nome             Varchar(100)
DataNascimento   DateTime
```

**Classe** (pseudo-linguagem):

```
class Pessoa
{
    int Id;
    string Nome;
    DateTime DataNascimento;
}
```

### Uso

Usando um ORM, o programador não precisa se importar em escrever as *query's* para consultas, inserções, etc. Isso é feito através da linguagem de programação, o ORM expõe uma API para lidar com estas operações.

Exemplo:

**Sem ORM:**

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM PESSOAS";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

DataReader reader = command.Execute();
List<Pessoas> pessoas = new List<Pessoas>();

while(row = reader.Next())
{
    pessoas.Add(new Pessoa
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt(row["Id"]),
        Nome = row["Nome"].ToString(),
        DataNascimento = Convert.ToDate(row["DataNascimento"]);
    };
}
```

**Com ORM:**

```
List<Pessoas> pessoas = database.Pessoas.SelectAll().ToList();
```

Perceba que isso é um exemplo simplório e apenas ilustrativo. Cada ORM tem uma forma diferente de trabalhar (esta é uma forma que eu inventei).

### Mapeamento

Existem diversas formas de se mapear uma classe com uma tabela, isso depende da ferramenta. Por exemplo, o Hibernate (Java) permite que o mapeamento seja feito usando arquivos XML, ou anotações na classe (modelo). O Entity Framework (.NET) permite que este mapeamento diretamente na classe (o nome da classe vira o nome da tabela e as propriedades viram as colunas) ou usando atributos (os DataAnnotations).

Answer (score 9):

Estritamente falando a única função que um ORM **deve** ter é o mapeamento do modelo de dados encontrado no banco de dados (relacional) para o modelo encontrado na aplicação (orientado a objeto).

A fonte de dados não precisa ser necessariamente um banco de dados, principalmente não precisa ser relacional, mas isso é o mais comum.

Isso significa mapear as tabelas do banco de dados com as classes da aplicação, não necessariamente de um para um (embora seja o mais comum) traduzindo os tipos de dados, já que normalmente não há uma relação direta. Conhece alguma linguagem de programação que tem um tipo `varchar`? Não, né? Então, isso é uma função do ORM.

Em geral o que o ORM faz é diminuir o *boilerplate* do acesso aos dados em modelos diferentes através de uma abstração do modelo. Isso é diferente do acesso direto relacional onde se enxerga tudo como tabelas mesmo. Com o ORM a aplicação acessa os dados de uma forma menos vinculada à fonte de dados.

É comum ORMs implementarem um [repositório](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101692/101) e terem uma linguagem própria para acesso aos dados, mas isso não é obrigatório. Isso costuma criar uma abstração que permite a adaptação para qualquer tipo de fonte de dados (dependendo da flexibilidade do ORM). Em geral há operações para a realização de um CRUD, mas novamente, isso é extensão da funcionalidade básica.

Não é simples fazer isso corretamente por causa do [*Object-relational Impedance Mismatch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch).

Claro que o ORM pode e frequentemente faz mais que isso. Há controvérsias se deveria. Há vantagens e desvantagens em fazer mais. É comum chamar esses *frameworks* mais "leves" (que só fazem o mínimo que um ORM deve fazer) de micro ORM.

[Há uma pergunta sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14225/101).

[Há detratores do padrão](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/12/01/orm-offensive-anti-pattern.html). Há até um [artigo bem famoso sobre o assunto](http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/the-vietnam-of-computer-science/). Muitas dessas críticas estão mais na forma como ORMs mais conhecidos funcionam do que no padrão em si. O mapeamento é necessário de alguma forma, o problema é exagerar. [Uma visão menos parcial](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/OrmHate.html). Note que eu sou só o mensageiro, não atirem em mim se não gostarem do que está escrito aqui.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).