# Entitiy framework pra JAVA?

Tags: java, entity-framework, framework, crud

Boa noite galera, sou novo na área da programação. Então, eu estive olhando alguns artigos e assistindo vídeos sobre o framework Entity para C #, eu gostaria de saber se em Java existem também alguns frameworks que fazem a mesma função ou similar em relação ao CRUD?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O que você procura é um **ORM**, *Object-Relational Mapping*, assim são chamados esses *frameworks* para mapear e facilitar o acesso às entidades do banco através de modelos de classes.

Aqui tem uma ótima pergunta com ótimas repostas falando sobre ORM: [Quais são as funções de um ORM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138938/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-um-orm)

Bem, o *framework* ORM talvez mais conhecido para `Java` talvez seja o `Hibernate`, que inclusive tem uma versão para `.NET` chamada `NHibernate`, que é "concorrente" do `EntityFramework`.

Você pode baixar e ver a documentação no site oficial http://hibernate.org/

Se quiser um tutorial com exemplo de configuração e código, aqui tem um bom pra você começar: [netbeans.org/hibernate](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/hibernate-java-se_pt_BR.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Ricardo, ajudou bastante!