# Qual a diferença entre ActiveRecord e Repository?

Tags: design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, active-record, repository

Estou lendo um livro de POO em PHP que chama PHP Programando com Orientação a Objetos [Pablo Dall'Oglio] e fiquei meio confuso com esses dois *design patterns*, principalmente quando ele faz uso do Repository utilizando ActiveRecord. Vale ressaltar que nos exemplos não contém uso de namespace, prepare (SQL Injection), pois neste capítulo do livro não foi tratado disto ainda.

```
<?php
abstract class Record
{
protected $data; //Array contendo os dados do objeto

public function __construct($id = NULL)
{
    if ($id) { //Se o ID for informado
        //Carrega o objeto correspondente
        $object = $this->load($id);
        if ($object) {
            $this->fromArray($object->toArray());
        }
    }
}

public function __clone() 
{
    unset($this->data['id']);
}

public function __set($prop, $value)
{
    if (method_exists($this, 'set_'.$prop)) {
        //Executa o método set_<propriedade>
        call_user_func(array($this, 'set_'.$prop), $value);
    } else {
        if ($value === NULL) {
            unset($this->data[$prop]);
        } else {
            $this->data[$prop] = $value;
        }
    }
}

public function __get($prop) 
{
    if (method_exists($this, 'get_'.$prop)) {
        //Executa o método get_<propriedade>
        return call_user_func(array($this, 'get_'.$prop));
    } else {
        if(isset($this->data[$prop])) {
            return $this->data[$prop];
        }
    }
}

public function __isset($prop)
{
    return isset($this->data[$prop]);
}

private function getEntity()
{
    $class = get_class($this); //Obtém o nome da classe
    return constant("{$class}::TABLENAME"); //Retorna a constante de classe TABLENAME
}

public function fromArray($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}

public function toArray()
{
    return $this->data;
}

public function store()
{
    $prepared = $this->prepare($this->data);

    //Verifica se tem ID ou se existe na base de dados
    if (empty($this->data['id']) or (!$this->load($this->id))) {
        //Incrementa o ID
        if (empty($this->data['id'])) {
            $this->id = $this->getLast() + 1;
            $prepared['id'] = $this->id;
        }

        //Cria uma instrução de insert
        $sql = "INSERT INTO {$this->getEntity()} " . '(' . implode(', ', array_keys($prepared)) . ')' . " VALUES " . '(' . implode(', ', array_values($prepared)) . ')';
    } else {
        //Monta a string de UPDATE
        $sql = "UPDATE {$this->getEntity()}";
        //Monta os pares: coluna=valor,...
        if ($prepared) {
            foreach($prepared as $column => $value) {
                if ($column !== 'id') {
                    $set[] = "{$column} = {$value}";
                }
            }
        }
        $sql .= " SET " . implode(', ', $set);
        $sql .= 'WHERE id = ' . (int) $this->date['id'];
    }

    //Obtém transação ativa
    if ($conn = Transaction::get()) {
        Transaction::log($sql);
        $result = $conn->exec($sql);
        return $result;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Não há transação ativa');
    }
}

public function load($id)
{
    //Monta instrução de SELECT
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$this->getEntity()}";
    $sql .= ' WHERE id = ' . (int) $id;

    //Obtém transação ativa
    if ($conn = Transaction::get()) {
        //Cria a mensagem de log e executa a consulta
        Transaction::log($sql);
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        //Se retornou algum dado
        if ($result) {
            //Retorna os dados em forma de objeto
            $object = $result->fetchObject(get_class($this));
        }
        return $object;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Não há transação ativa!!');
    }
}

public function delete($id = NULL)
{
    //O ID é o parâmetro ou a propriedade ID
    $id = $id ? $id : $this->id;

    //Mostra a string de UPDATE
    $sql = "DELETE FROM {$this->getEntity()}";
    $sql .= ' WHERE id = ' . (int) $this->data['id'];

    //Obtém transação ativa
    if ($conn = Transaction::get()) {
        //Faz o log e executa o SQL
        Transaction::log($sql);
        $result = $conn->exec($sql);
        return $result; //Retorna o resultado
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Não há transação ativa!!');
    }
}

public static function find($id)
{
    $classname = get_called_class();
    $ar = new $classname;
    return $ar->load($id);
}

private function getLast()
{
    if($conn = Transaction::get()) {
        $sql = "SELECT max(id) FROM {$this->getEntity()}";

        //Cria log e executa instrução SQL
        Transaction::log($sql);
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        //Retorna os dados do banco
        $row = $result->fetch();
        return $row[0];
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Não há transação ativa!!');
    }
}

public function prepare($data)
{
    $prepared = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if(is_scalar($value)) {
            $prepared[$key] = $this->escape($value);
        }
    }
    return $prepared;
}

public function escape($value)
{
    if (is_string($value) and (!empty($value))) {
        //Adiciona \ em aspas
        $value = addslashes($value);
        return "'$value'";
    } else if (is_bool($value)) {
        return $value ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
    } else if ($value !== '') {
        return $value;
    } else {
        return "NULL";
    }
}
}
?>
```

**Classe Produto**

```
<?php
class Produto extends Record {
const TABLENAME = 'produto';
}
?>
```

**Classe Expression**

```
<?php
abstract class Expression 
{
//Operadores lógicos
const AND_OPERATOR = 'AND ';
const OR_OPERATOR = 'OR ';

//Metodo que retornara uma expressão em string
abstract public function dump();
}
?>
```

**Classe Criteria**

```
<?php
class Criteria extends Expression 
{
private $expressions; //Armazena a lista de expressões
private $operators; //Armazena a lista de operadores
private $properties; //Propriedades do critério (ORDER BY, LIMIT, ...)

public function __construct()
{
    $this->expressions = array();
    $this->operators = array();
}

public function add(Expression $expression, $operator = self::AND_OPERATOR)
{ 
    //Na primeira vez, não precisamos concatenar
    if (empty($this->expressions)) {
        $operator = NULL;
    }

    //Agrega o resultado da expressão para a lista de expressões
    $this->expressions[] = $expression;
    $this->operators[] = $operator;
}

public function dump()
{
    //Concatena a lista de expressões
    if (is_array($this->expressions)) {
        if (count($this->expressions) > 0) {
            $result = '';
            foreach ($this->expressions as $i => $expression) {
                $operator = $this->operators[$i];
                //Concatena o operador com a respectiva expressão
                $result .= $operator . $expression->dump() . ' ';
            }
            $result = trim($result);
            return "({$result})";
        }
    }
}

public function setProperty($property, $value)
{
    if (isset($value)) {
        $this->properties[$property] = $value;
    } else {
        $this->properties[$property] = NULL;
    }
}

public function getProperty($property)
{
    if (isset($this->properties[$property])) {
        return $this->properties[$property];
    }
}
}
?>
```

**Classe Filter**

```
<?php
class Filter extends Expression
{
public $variable;
public $operator;
public $value;

public function __construct($variable, $operator, $value) 
{
    $this->variable = $variable;
    $this->operator = $operator;

    //Transforma o valor de acordo com certas regras de tipo
    $this->value = $this->transform($value);
}

private function transform($value)
{
    //Caso seja um array
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $x) {
            if (is_integer($x)) {
                $foo[] = $x;
            } else if (is_string($x)) {
                $foo[] = "'$x'";
            }
        }
        //Converte o array em string separada por ","
        $result = '(' . implode(',', $foo) . ')';
    } else if (is_string($value)) {
        $result = "'$value'";
    } else if (is_null($value)) {
        $result = 'NULL';
    } else if (is_bool($value)) {
        $result = $value ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
    } else {
        $result = $value;
    }
    //Retorna o valor
    return $result;
}

public function dump()
{
    //Concatena a expressão
    return "{$this->variable} {$this->operator} {$this->value}";
}
}  
?>
```

**Classe Repository**

```
<?php
class Repository 
{
private $activeRecord;

public function __construct($class)
{
    $this->activeRecord = $class;
}

public function load(Criteria $criteria = NULL)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . constant($this->activeRecord.'::TABLENAME');
    if ($criteria) {
        $expression = $criteria->dump();
        if ($expression) {
            $sql .= ' WHERE ' . $expression;
        }
        $order = $criteria->getProperty('ORDER');
        $limit = $criteria->getProperty('LIMIT');
        $offset = $criteria->getProperty('OFFSET');
        if ($order) {
            $sql .= ' ORDER ' . $order;
        }
        if ($limit) {
            $sql .= ' LIMIT ' . $limit;
        }
        if ($offset) {
            $sql .= ' OFFSET ' . $offset;
        }
    }
    if ($conn = Transaction::get()) {
        Transaction::log($sql);
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $results = array();
        if ($result) {
            while ($row = $result->fetchObject($this->activeRecord)) {
                $results[] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $results;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Não há transição ativa!!');
    }
}

public function delete(Criteria $criteria = NULL)
{
    $sql = "DELETE FROM " . constant($this->activeRecord.'::TABLENAME');
    if ($criteria) {
        $expression = $criteria->dump();
        if ($expression) {
            $sql .= ' WHERE ' . $expression;
        }
    }
    if ($conn = Transaction::get()) {
        Transaction::log($sql);
        $result = $conn->exec($sql);
        return $result;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Não há transição ativa!!');
    }
}

public function count(Criteria $criteria = NULL)
{
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM " . constant($this->activeRecord.'::TABLENAME');
    if ($criteria) {
        $expression = $criteria->dump();
        if ($expression) {
            $sql .= ' WHERE ' . $expression;
        }
    }
    if ($conn = Transaction::get()) {
        Transaction::log($sql);
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result) {
            $row = $result->fetch();
        }
        return $row[0];
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Não há transição ativa!!!');
    }
}
}
?>
```

**Por fim o exemplo de utilização**

```
<?php
require_once 'classes/api/Transaction.php';
require_once 'classes/api/Connection.php';
require_once 'classes/api/Expression.php';
require_once 'classes/api/Criteria.php';
require_once 'classes/api/Repository.php';
require_once 'classes/api/Record.php';
require_once 'classes/api/Filter.php';
require_once 'classes/api/Logger.php';
require_once 'classes/api/LoggerTXT.php';
require_once 'classes/model/Produto.php';

try {
//Inicia a transação com a base de dados
Transaction::open('estoque');

//Define o arquivo de LOG
Transaction::setLogger(new LoggerTXT('tmp/log_collection_update.txt'));

//Define o criterio de seleção
$criteria = new Criteria;
$criteria->add(new Filter('preco_venda', '<=', 35));
$criteria->add(new Filter('origem', '=', 'N'));

//Cria o repositório
$repository = new Repository('Produto');
//Carrega os objetos conforme o critério
$produtos = $repository->load($criteria);
if ($produtos) {
    //Percorre todos os objetos
    foreach ($produtos as $produto) {
        $produto->preco_venda *= 1.3;
        $produto->store(); //Método da classe Record
    }
}
Transaction::close();

} catch (Exception $e) {
Transaction::rollback();
print $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Melhore sua pergunta colocando as definições que o livro trás e, se houver exemplos de códigos, coloque-os também. Não esqueça de referenciar o livro e autor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O **[Active Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)** é um padrão de projeto mais simples que basicamente encapsula uma linha de um banco de dados ou outro mecanismo de persistência para a aplicação consumir incluindo as regras de negócio e o mecanismo de persistência. Ele é praticamente um *buffer* com algum controle sobre sua atualização.

O **Repository** é uma infraestrutura mais complexa cuidando de todo o processo de manipulação dos dados. O mecanismo de acesso fica separado da regra de negócio. Costuma-se dizer que ele é ignorante em relação à persistência, ou seja, a persistência pode ocorrer de formas diferentes conforme a necessidade. Curioso não ter um artigo na Wikipedia, faz pensar.

Então a forma exata é diferente, mas o objetivo é basicamente o mesmo.

Hoje o padrão do repositório é muito mais usado devido a sua facilidade de troca de persistência e testes. Tem uma [pergunta sobre ele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101692/101).

Se um é usado junto com o outro me parece que bobagem está sendo feita.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Peço desculpas por alguns erros, minha primeira vez perguntado aqui. Então, no livro PHP Programando com Orientação a Objetos do Pablo Dall'Oglio ele faz uma sequência de passos. Primeiro ele explica ActiveRecord e constrói uma classe Record (Layer Supertype) que contem métodos para carregar, excluir, atualizar e inserir objetos no banco. Após isso ele constrói a classe Produto que extende a classe Record. Depois ele explica o conceito de Query Object, Composite e Repository, em que o Repositório utiliza a classe Produto para manipular seus objeto.