# Diferença entre DTO e ViewModel?

Tags: terminologia, design-pattern, viewmodel

Nessa pergunta podemos vero que é ViewModel: [Pra que serve uma ViewModel no ASP.NET MVC?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/305207/pra-que-serve-uma-viewmodel-no-asp-net-mvc)

Nessa outra pergunta podemos ver o que é DTO: [O que é um DTO?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31362/o-que-%c3%a9-um-dto)

Mas afinal de contas:

- Qual a diferença entre DTO e ViewModel?
- Quando devemos usar um ou outro ou até mesmo os dois?

<sub>E ainda tem essa aqui [Utilização de DTO e ViewModel em projeto ASP.Net MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33005/utiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-dto-e-viewmodel-em-projeto-asp-net-mvc) que eu acredito não ser duplicada</sub>

Comment: Boa +1, eu andei pesquisando sobre, mas pra mim não fez muito sentido quando utilizar um e outro, vou aguardar uma resposta aqui!

Comment: Eu já havia pesquisado há um tempo, mas também não havia entendido. Normalmente uso ViewModel em Web e DTO em apis. mas porque apreendi assim, sem um porquê(o que é péssimo)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lá na [pergunta sobre DTO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31362/101) já tem uma boa resposta sobre o que ele é, exceto pelo fato de [falar em campos como se fossem atributos, mas é um erro que 99,99% das pessoas cometem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101) mesmo :).

Vamos esquecer um pouco, e só por um momento inicial, a terminologia usada no MVC para não confundir. Vamos usar a terminologia do banco de dados que é mais comum as pessoas entenderem.

O DTO é uma forma de organizar informações na aplicação que vem de alguma(s) fonte(s), geralmente um banco de dados, mas pode ser outro mecanismo. Podemos entender o DTO como uma *view* que você já deve conhecer do banco de dados. Não que seja exatamente isto, mas só para entender. O DTO pega dados da fonte de dados e monta um objeto fácil de usar usado pela aplicação. Em geral o DTO faz um mapeamento simples e não tem comportamento. Ele tem relação direta com a fonte de dados, e pode ser usado em diversas partes da aplicação apenas para consumo.

Geralmente quando este tipo de objeto tem comportamento ele passa ser um padrão chamado de [Active Record](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189082/101). Em alguns casos usa-se o Domain Object ou outra terminologia com pequenas sutis diferenças.

O DTO pega os dados de uma fonte, provavelmente uma **tabela** de um banco de dados, e monta um objeto simples. O AR permite ter uma lógica de como a transferência será feita, e até mesmo lógica de negócios nela, ainda que alguns autores indicam que aí já seja outra coisa.

O DTO é um mecanismo que pode ser usado como parte do modelo do *model* do MVC, mas geralmente é o AR que é usado.

Não gosto da pergunta sobre DTO e *view model*, acho que está confuso, provavelmente errado e segue uma linha específica de desenvolvimento que eu não gosto. Vou ignorá-la.

Continuando na analogia com banco de dados o *view model*, é como se fosse uma [*view* de um banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35413/101) que você já conhece, porém apenas dentro da sua aplicação. Ele é um **modelo para a *view*** do MVC. Ele não é um modelo para a base de dados. Claro que ele terá que se comunicar com o modelo da base de dados para pegar dados, mas o consumo é da *view* do MVC.

Há muitos casos simples que usar um objeto via DTO, AR, DO, ou o que seja adequado e simples, há uma relação fácil entre esse objeto e o que vai usar na *view* do MVC. Mas há casos que não é tão simples, você precisa de **objeto que será consumido pela *view*** que é mais complexo que é composto por um subconjunto de campos desses objetos que se ligam à base de dados, ou de campos criados só nesses objetos porque a base de dados ou objetos da aplicação não os provê, ou ainda precisa de dados que estão em diversos objetos e fica complicado usá-los separadamente, então compila-se (no sentido de juntar, não de analisar um código fonte :) ) tudo isto em um objeto que se encaixe na demanda da *view* do MVC. Ou seja o *view model* mapeia para a *view* do MVC, enquanto que o *model* mapeia com a base de dados.

Então o *view model* é como se fosse um `SELECT` pré-estabelecido que gera um objeto pronto e fácil de usar na *view*.

Não há qualquer relação entre os dois. Achar que o DTO é um mecanismo do *view model*, na minha concepção, é errado, mas é possível fazer essa analogia como um DTO entre o modelo do MVC e a visão do MVC.

Se não tem uma *view* na jogada, não tem porque usar um *view model*. E *view* pode ser de um padrão de projeto conhecido como o MVC, MVP, ou MVVM, e provavelmente em RUI (que eu ainda estou estudando, e parece bom), mas podem ser *views* fora desses padrões conhecidos, tem gente que usa um M(odel)V(iew) e um *model view* pode ser útil mesmo em casos assim.

DTO é um mecanismo primitivo. Sozinho, em sua essência, ele é útil em aplicações simples e diretas. É quase impossível ter uma aplicação com base de dados que não tenha alguma forma de DTO ou suas derivação, geralmente um AR, mesmo que não pareça, já que há linguagens e *frameworks* que abstraem isso para você. O *viewmodel* não é necessário a não ser que o mecanismo que se comunica com a *view* exija, o que é comum nos *frameworks* MVC por aí, mas é mais por deficiência deles.

Pra fica claro, o *model* do MVC é sempre uma forma, quase sempre mais sofisticada, de DTO, em geral até mais sofisticada do que um AR. Muitas vezes o *model* é representado por um repositório, que é cheio de ARs e outros mecanismos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Compreendi a diferença, minha visão(posso ter entendido algo errado) eles são parecidos, mas tem finalidades totalmente diferentes. Pelo que entendi eu já usava da forma correta, só não sabia o porquê. Só me ficou uma pequena dúvida(para deixar mais claro o que já está claro), aqui você diz `O DTO pega os dados de uma fonte, provavelmente uma tabela` seria errado ter um *select* "customizado" que traga dados de 2 ou 3 tabelas e passado para um DTO  com esses campos ou nesse caso seria AR?

Comment: Não sei dizer com propriedade, eu acho que não, pelo que eu entendo, e se estamos falando da mesma coisa, é tranquilo, desde que o objweto resultado deste DTO seja simples, ou seja, voc|ê quer o nome do cliente, mas ele não está na tabela base para o DTO que só tem um ID do cliente, acho ok pegar o nome lá ter no objeto diretamente, porque toda aplicação vai precisa disto, o que é diferente de uma *view* específica precisar dele. Mas não tenho certeza, posso pesquisar. Porque o que eu acho certo é fazer o que precisa, que nome vai dar é secundário, embora eu goste de dar o nome certo, ajuda...

Comment: ...entender melhor, comunicar melhor.

Comment: Concordo plenamente ;) Para finalizar, sem querer folgar, mas já folgando. estou pesquisando mas não estou achando sobre `MVVP e RUI` que você citou. alguma indicação de artigo sobre?

Comment: O certo era MVVM :D o RUI é novo mesmo não tem muita coisa

Comment: kkk eu suspeitava, mas como tem tanta coisa, vai que rsrs. Vou pesquisar mais, logo menos pergunto aqui sobre. xD

Answer (score 6):

#### TL;DR

Use **DTO** para modelar a API do seu sistema ou componente (backend), ou seja, como o "mundo externo" vê o modelo de dados.

Use **ViewModel** para modelar os dados expostos na interface com o usuário (frontend).

#### Compreendendo abstrações no backend

Quando comecei a programar, eu tentava pesar num sistema como um todo, desde o banco até a "telinha" como uma coisa só. Tentava refletir, tanto quando possível, o banco de dados na tela e vice-versa.

Pulando uma década, cada vez fica mais claro que isto não funciona, por várias razões.

Num mundo de micro-serviços - ou mesmo num sistema grande bem organizado - é importante que cada peça da engrenagem funcione com uma responsabilidade e um modelo bem definido. Entretanto, um *endpoint* pode ser bem diferente da forma como os dados são realmente armazenados, se é que um banco de dados existe mesmo. Detalhes de implementação não importam para quem usa o sistema.

Portanto, o projeto de um sistema moderno começa com a definição da API. Os desenvolvedores podem usar qualquer tipo de bancos de dados e então, na hora de representar ou receber os dados do mundo externo, o padrão DTO é aplicado.

Um sistema complexo pode agregar dados de diversas fontes diferentes e criar um DTO como um valor de retorno. Ou o contrário: ele recebe uma requisição com um corpo em JSON, por exemplo, que algum framework pode automaticamente mapear para um DTO, e no final o sistema pode destrinchar aquela informação e tomar diferentes ações.

#### Compreendendo abstrações no frontend

Um processo muito semelhante acontece nos frontends modernos, principalmente quando falamos de Apps escritos em React.js, Android e muitos outros.

O frontend moderno deixou de ser um simples formulário baseado numa tecnologia de templates, onde você preenche alguns valores e renderiza para o usuário.

Os SPAs (*Single Page Applications*) e mesmo Mobile Apps podem consumir informações de uma miríade de sistemas.

Portanto, é comum em designs modernos você projetar o frontend de forma completamente independente do(s) backend(s) por traz do sistema.

Assim, você precisa definir models das views ou View Model. Os dados podem vir de diferentes requisições a diferentes servidores, de interações com o usuário, do ambiente ou navegador, etc.

### Considerações

Os dois padrões são usados para a representação de dados, porém geralmente em camadas completamente diferentes e isoladas de um sistema ou conjunto de sistemas.

É importante entender os conceitos na prática, já que tecnologias e frameworks podem, de uma forma ou de outra, apropriar-se dos conceitos e tornar confusa a aplicação deles.