# Passando código para página cshtml asp.net core razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Como que eu passo esse código que está em uma página .cs para uma página cshtml.

```
 ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

Está página é a layout, não possui Model e nem DTO.

Obrigado

Comment: Sua página tem uma Model ou um DTO?

Comment: @AlexandreCavaloti aconselho a leitura dessa resposta [Diferença entre DTO e ViewModel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/305510/88361)

Comment: @renato, depende muito, acho que seria mais viável você indicar o problema que está tendo(por que deseja o `ApplicationUser` na `View`), talvez a solução seja diferente da forma como está tentando.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem a pergunta, mas vc pode tentar usar o ViewData para enviar dados de um arquivo .cs para um .cshtml
Exemplo .cs:

```
public IActionResult Index(){ ViewData["Codigo"] = user; }
```

Exemplo .cshtml:

```
<h1> @ViewData["Codigo"] </h1>
```