# Como ocultar propriedade na listagem do EFCore

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Olá,
Estou com uma dúvida referente a WebAPI com EFCore do ASP.NET Core.

Possuo minhas entidades de Serviço, Profissional, Usuário e Agendamentos, onde no serviço possuo uma chave estrangeira para o profissional e no agendamento para profissional e usuário.

Quando faço uma requisição para o *endpoint* /servicos, recebo o seguinte JSON:

```js
[
  {
    "descricao": "Servico Primário",
    "valor": 109.99,
    "profissional": {
      "servicos": [],
      "nome": "Profissional",
      "cpf": "00000000001",
      "endereco": "Rua A",
      "idade": 22,
      "email": "profissional@email.com",
      "senha": "123456789",
      "id": 1
    },
    "agendamentos": [
      {
        "data": "2019-08-22T19:30:40.573",
        "finalizado": false,
        "usuario": null,
        "id": 1
      }
    ],
    "id": 1
  }
]
```

A estrutura acima é gerada seguindo este código:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Fusion.Domain.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Fusion.Infra.Data.Repositories
{
    public class ServicoRepository : BaseRepository<Servico>
    {
        public override IList<Servico> SelectAll()
        {
            return context.Servicos
                .Include("Profissional")
                .Include("Agendamentos")
                .ToList();
        }

        public override Servico Select(int id)
        {
            return SelectAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, como faço para ocultar nessa requisição em específica os campos profissional.senha, profissional.servicos e agendamentos.usuario?

Comment: infelizmente usando rest a única forma seria fazer um outro dto sem o atributo em questão e mapea-lo, pra conseguir trazer resultados de maneira mais dinamica, eu acredito que você precisa tentar algo como o graphql

Comment: Foi exatamente isso que eu fiz e que deu certo Lucas. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 5):

Você pode ignorar uma propriedade de ser serializada decorando-a com o `JsonIgnore`

```
public class Profissional
{        
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Cpf { get; set; }
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Mas quando uso o JsonIgnore ele também vai ignorar as requisições em POST.

Comment: Eu ia sugerir para você fazer como na sua resposta :D. Uma leitura interessante é [Diferença entre DTO e ViewModel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/305301/diferen%c3%a7a-entre-dto-e-viewmodel)

Answer (score 0):

A minha solução, para quem desejar aplicar, foi o uso de uma classe ViewDTO com as propriedades que eu gostaria de representar na tela.

Classe para Mapeamento usando o `AutoMapper`:

```cs
using AutoMapper;
using Fusion.Domain.Entities;
using Fusion.Infra.Data.DTO;

namespace Fusion.Infra.Data.AutoMapper
{
    public static class FusionMapper
    {
        public static MapperConfiguration mapper = new MapperConfiguration(conf => {
            conf.CreateMap<Profissional, ProfissionalViewDTO>();
        });
    }
}
```

Classe ProfissionalViewDTO:

```cs
using Fusion.Domain.Entities;

namespace Fusion.Infra.Data.DTO
{
    public class ProfissionalViewDTO
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string CPF { get; set; }
        public string Endereco { get; set; }
        public int Idade { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

E no meu repositório da camada de acesso ao contexto:

```cs
namespace Fusion.Infra.Data.Repositories
{
    public class ProfissionalRepository : BaseRepository<Profissional>
    {
        IMapper mapper = FusionMapper.mapper.CreateMapper();

        public new IList<ProfissionalViewDTO> SelectAll()
        {
            return context.Profissionais
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => mapper.Map<Profissional, ProfissionalViewDTO>(x))
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

E por fim, minha classe de domínio do Profissional:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Fusion.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Profissional : Pessoa
    {        
        public ICollection<Servico> Servicos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Onde esta herdando uma classe Pessoa:

```cs
namespace Fusion.Domain.Entities
{
    public abstract class Pessoa : BaseEntity
    {
        public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
        public virtual string CPF { get; set; }
        public virtual string Endereco { get; set; }
        public virtual int Idade { get; set; }
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual string Senha { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Obs.: Apliquei para testes numa outra classe da minha aplicação, mas pode ser replicado para as outras usando do mesmo conceito de ViewDTO.**